# The destructor is not called when pthread is terminated

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

I have a pthread which I wanted to use to create a class interface

```
void* DmaInterfaceThread(void* args)
{
    sem_wait(&DmaInterfaceSemaphore);
    printf("IceNET 2 ---> Dma Interface Thread \n");

    interface *pinterface;

    while(true)
    {
        if(CreateInterface == 1) 
        {
            pinterface = new interface();
            CreateInterface = 0;   
        }

        if(DmaInterfaceTerminate == 1) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The class looks as follows:

```
class interface 
{
    public:
        void setLength( double len );
        double getLength( void );

        interface();   // This is the constructor declaration
        ~interface();  // This is the destructor: declaration

    private:
        double length;
};
 
// Constructor
interface::interface(void) 
{
    cout << "IceNET 3 ---> Interface Created" << endl;
}

// Destructor
interface::~interface(void) 
{
    cout << "IceNET 4 ---> Interface Destroyed" << endl;
}

void interface::setLength( double len ) 
{
    length = len;
}

double interface::getLength( void ) 
{
    return length;
}
```

But when the DmaInterfaceTerminate flag is set to shutdown the thread the program terminates but the destructor of class is not called

I can see the print out from the constructor when the class interface is created but when the pthread is terminated there is no print out from the destructor, so it is not even called

Has anyone seen this problem before and could help me?

Many Thanks

Comment: why do you exepct that the destructor of `interface` is called? Can you point to the line in the code where you destroy the object?

Comment: I can't spot a `delete` anywhere?

Comment: I thought this will happen automatically when I return from the thread

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I'm quite new to c++ ---> The "delete pinterface;" did the job I wanted to do

Comment: Generally, avoid `new`. Also, avoid pthreads, C++ has its own (and in many places superior) threading abstraction which is even portable. Concerning your Q, please extract a [mcve] first next time, it helps you find errors yourself. For example, you could have found out that your question has nothing to do with multithreading, you'd have the same behaviour with just one thread.

Comment: Destructors run automatically when an object goes out of scope. `pinterface` goes out of scope at the end of the function. But `pinterface` is a raw pointer, and raw pointers do nothing when destructed. If you want a pointer to be `delete`d at destruction, use a `unique_ptr`.